# Cannot get some feed via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I cannot get some feed via Graph API.
Before this April, I can get all feed via Graph API.
I have tried to do if there are some possibility of something wrong with my environment. 
I find that I can get all feed via Graph API on another server.
I have three server. They are same OS and PHP version. IP address are only different.
Is this Facebook bug?

Comment: Are you getting any error when you get no feed? Also check if you are using correct and valid access token.

Comment: I have no error. I already checked using access token. I can get almost of feed but some posts are lost.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the facebook explorer
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?

go there and choose your application

maybe your application have some error using the API !!

otherwise you have to install curl to your servers because the php-sdk is need curl to fetch data from the api

Comment: Yes I have already tried it. I have no error. I have three Facebook pages. I can get all feed from two of them. But some posts are lost from one of them. I also have tried to get feed from them on another server(same OS/ same PHP ver), I can get all feed from that three Facebook pages.

Comment: please try to install curl , if you don't know how to install this , please let me know more about your server's operating system , your control panel and php version 
generaly if you use Centos try `yum install curl` or Debian `apt-get install curl` in some systems it must be installed as a php extension php-curl php5-curl